# woocommerce show subcategories with their corresponding products below

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I would like to make a modification to my website(wordpress) that has woocommerce, which has the following structure:

-In the main page I show the categories: OK

-Within the categories, if they have subcategories, I would like the title (subcategory) + products of the subcategory below it to be displayed.

Example:

Subcategory1

product1 product2 product3

Subcategory2

product1 product2 product3

....

I can not find the way to do it, if there is someone who can advise me I would be very grateful, greetings and thank you very much

Comment: Keep in mind that will have downsides such as no pagination. If you want pagination for each category will be extra coding. On parent category list each sub category with 3-4 products and view all button. That will be much better approach (my opinion).

Comment: Good evening, I have tried the updated code and it does not work, I get an error in the categories that do not have a subcategory. In categories without subcategories, where the products should be shown directly when entering the category, they are not shown, I get this error: `Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function woocommerce_product_loop() in **\wp-content\themes\theme\woocommerce\archive-product.php:84 . the line 84 is: if ( woocommerce_product_loop() ) {`

Comment: the woocommerce version I use is 3.1.2, I can't update it because it would break the web design, sorry for the inconvenience, if I can fix it, I'll post the answer here when I have it, thanks !!

Answer (score 1):

As i mention in my comment i suggest to have limited number of products and view all button over listing all sub categories with all products in it. But you can tweek it to your needs. First make sure your theme support woocommerce read more here - https://woocommerce.com/document/woocommerce-theme-developer-handbook/#section-6 . Second create folder in your theme named woocommerce and create file archive-product.php inside of it place the following code.

```
<?php
/**
 * The Template for displaying product archives, including the main shop page which is a post type archive
 *
 * This template can be overridden by copying it to yourtheme/woocommerce/archive-product.php.
 *
 * HOWEVER, on occasion WooCommerce will need to update template files and you
 * (the theme developer) will need to copy the new files to your theme to
 * maintain compatibility. We try to do this as little as possible, but it does
 * happen. When this occurs the version of the template file will be bumped and
 * the readme will list any important changes.
 *
 * @see https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/
 * @package WooCommerce\Templates
 * @version 3.4.0
 */

defined( 'ABSPATH' ) || exit;

get_header( 'shop' );

/**
 * Hook: woocommerce_before_main_content.
 *
 * @hooked woocommerce_output_content_wrapper - 10 (outputs opening divs for the content)
 * @hooked woocommerce_breadcrumb - 20
 * @hooked WC_Structured_Data::generate_website_data() - 30
 */
do_action( 'woocommerce_before_main_content' );

?>
<header class="woocommerce-products-header">
    <?php if ( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_show_page_title', true ) ) : ?>
        <h1 class="woocommerce-products-header__title page-title"><?php woocommerce_page_title(); ?></h1>
    <?php endif; ?>

    <?php
    /**
     * Hook: woocommerce_archive_description.
     *
     * @hooked woocommerce_taxonomy_archive_description - 10
     * @hooked woocommerce_product_archive_description - 10
     */
    do_action( 'woocommerce_archive_description' );
    ?>
</header>
<?php
$term = get_queried_object();
$children = get_term_children($term->term_id,'product_cat');
if($term->parent == 0 && count($children) !== 0):       
    $sub_categories = get_terms([
        'taxonomy'    => 'product_cat',
        'hide_empty'  => true,
        'parent'      => get_queried_object_id()
    ]);
    foreach($sub_categories as $sub_cat):
        $args = array(
            'post_type'           => 'product',
            'post_status'         => 'publish',
            'posts_per_page'      => 3,
            'tax_query'     => array(
              array(
                'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
                'field'    => 'slug',
                'terms'    => $sub_cat->slug,
              )
            ),
        );
        $product = new WP_Query( $args );
        echo '<div class="sub-cat-title" style="text-align:center;"><h2>'.$sub_cat->name.'</h2></div>';
        wc_get_template( 'loop/loop-start.php' ); 
        while ( $product->have_posts() ) {
            $product->the_post();
        
            wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'product' );
        
        }
        wc_get_template( 'loop/loop-end.php' ); 
        echo '<div class="view-all-button" style="text-align:center;"><a href="'.get_term_link($sub_cat->term_id,'product_cat').'">'.__('View all','woocommerce').'</a></div>';
    endforeach;
else:
if ( woocommerce_product_loop() ) {

    /**
     * Hook: woocommerce_before_shop_loop.
     *
     * @hooked woocommerce_output_all_notices - 10
     * @hooked woocommerce_result_count - 20
     * @hooked woocommerce_catalog_ordering - 30
     */
    do_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop' );

    woocommerce_product_loop_start();

    if ( wc_get_loop_prop( 'total' ) ) {
        while ( have_posts() ) {
            the_post();

            /**
             * Hook: woocommerce_shop_loop.
             */
            do_action( 'woocommerce_shop_loop' );

            wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'product' );
        }
    }

    woocommerce_product_loop_end();

    /**
     * Hook: woocommerce_after_shop_loop.
     *
     * @hooked woocommerce_pagination - 10
     */
    do_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop' );
} else {
    /**
     * Hook: woocommerce_no_products_found.
     *
     * @hooked wc_no_products_found - 10
     */
    do_action( 'woocommerce_no_products_found' );
}
endif;
/**
 * Hook: woocommerce_after_main_content.
 *
 * @hooked woocommerce_output_content_wrapper_end - 10 (outputs closing divs for the content)
 */
do_action( 'woocommerce_after_main_content' );

/**
 * Hook: woocommerce_sidebar.
 *
 * @hooked woocommerce_get_sidebar - 10
 */
do_action( 'woocommerce_sidebar' );

get_footer( 'shop' );
```

The following code is tested on storefront theme - https://prnt.sc/213gpjr

Comment: Hello, thank you very much for your help, your code works as I wanted, however, in the categories that do not have subcategories, when entering the category nothing is shown, it appears empty, and I should get the products that correspond to that specific category.
Only in categories that have subcategories does this work.

I would like the categories that do not have a subcategory to show the products corresponding to it. Sorry if I didn't explain it well, and I thank you again.